# HTML/Javascript - Inconsistent positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm in the process of designing this site http://www.parisgaa.org/parisgaels and have a problem.

The image slider on the homepage messes up sometimes. Most of the time it works and looks fine, but other times its positioning seems to get messed up and it appears underneath the content that should be below it (i.e. with that content overlapping the image). You should be able to replicate this in Chrome - just refresh a couple of times.

I'd appreciate any help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to edit a line in the slider file

```
js/slider.js



.wrap('<div class="bx-window" style="width:'+childrenMaxWidth+'px; height:'+wrapperHeight+'px; position:relative; overflow:hidden;"></div>')
            .css({
              height: '999999px',
              position: 'relative',
                top: '-'+(origTop)+'px'
            });
```

Within his you will need to define a height that works for your images like

```
.wrap('<div class="bx-window" style="width:'+childrenMaxWidth+'px; height:400px; position:relative; overflow:hidden;"></div>')
            .css({
              height: '999999px',
              position: 'relative',
                top: '-'+(origTop)+'px'
            });
```

The problem isn't your implementation rather the script you are using. You could try using a different script but hopefully this adjustment will do the trick for you!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The site is responsive, so I'd probably have to apply a class to the container in the slider.js file and use media queries to resize it. I'll probably just use the responsive slider I've found after a quick search. Thanks again!

Comment: If this worked for you please click the checkmark under my score :)

Answer (score 0):

Try making the image slider position relative:

```
style = "position:relative;"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be a problem with whatever jQuery plugin you're using for the image slider. The height of the `.bx-window` element isn't being evaluated correctly for some reason  (for me it's in the ballpark of 20-30px instead of 420px). I would try out a different slider (there's ton's of jQuery image sliders out there, just google it), but if that's not an option, it would probably be fairly trivial to fix it yourself in their code. Good luck!